# Prove that $\mathbb{R} \nsim \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The task is to prove that $\mathbb{R} \nsim \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

I know how easy it is to prove this once I can use cardinality, but I can't. I need to show that a bijection between those sets doesn't exist (or by using Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem).

The injection $f:\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is easy: 
$$ f(h)=g_h, g_h:\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g_h(x)=h$$

So, $k(\mathbb{R}) \leq k(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$.

What I struggle to do is to prove that $k(\mathbb{R}) \neq k(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show it for $\Bbb R$ vs $2^{\Bbb R}$?

Comment: You mean by showing that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \nsim \mathbb{R}$?